# Problems with Apple's Security Update 2011-005 (Lion)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why folders keep shifting their positions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24926/why-folders-keep-shifting-their-positions)

Today I downloaded Apple Security Update 2011-005 for Lion (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1447). However, I got some issues here. After the update I noticed that some of the folders on my Desktop was rearranged. Moreover, my Mac started slowing down.

Does anybody else have same problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The update replaces 3 files, all pertaining to your system's keychain. They are as follows:

```
/System/Library/Keychains/EVRoots.plist
/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain
/System/Library/Keychains/SystemTrustSettings.plist
```

It is impossible that the update has caused your problems. Look elsewhere.

Comment: Hmmmm... Any thoughts what could cause folder rearrangement?

Comment: I'm with [cksum](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/10355/cksum) - they are correlated in time only, but not caused by each other.

Answer (score 1):

The arrangement of icons on the desktop and in folders is controlled by the (usually hideen) file .DS_Store. If you deleted this file or it became corrupted, your icons may have shifted around. It should not affect the speed of your computer though.

Comment: I did not delete or somehow change it :/

Comment: There is some discussion about this being a known bug with Lion

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3216766?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: My icons/folders moved around as well after this update.