# Why folders keep shifting their positions?

Tags: macos, folders

I bought a new MacBook Pro 15-inch model with highest specifications in this June. I also installed newest version of Mac OS X, Lion (updated).

Yesterday, I turned on my computer and noticed that some of the folders on my desktop were rearranged. Today, the same thing happened again. I would like to ask you what the possible problem could be?

I did not touch any of the ".DS_Store" files.

Comment: Does your Desktop size ever change, for example by sometimes connecting an external monitor or a projector?

Comment: Did not try actually. Only folders are changing every time I turn on my "Mac".

Comment: Can you close your older question, since this seems to be an ongoing problem for you, not related to Security Update?
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/problems-with-apples-security-update-2011-005-lion

Comment: This one is actually related to that you mentioned, however there is a difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have auto arrange turned on (and it says "Arrange by: None", please try the following things.

1) If you are only experience problems on the Desktop, but not in any other finder window, please delete the preference file *com.apple.desktop.plist* from your user/library/preferences folder

2) If that does not solve problem, delete the .Ds_Store files in any folders you are having problems with, including the Desktop and let Lion recreate them

3) Lastly, as I mentioned in your other thread, this does seem to be a known problem in Lion. Please keep an eye on [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3216766?start=0&tstart=0) and [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15832013#15832013) for other solutions and/or possible resolution in a future Lion update.

Comment: Also, as an interim solution you could try the following. If icons are arranged the way you like, go to the terminal and make sure you are in the right directory and run sudo cp .DS_Store DS_Storebak ; if the icons get scrambled, go back to the terminal and run it in reverse cp DS_Storebak .DS_Store